# Behaviour after deleting list item from List<item> in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have list `List <Bitmap> memory = new List<Bitmap>();`. I use this list for saving states of image in simple program for working with images. I want to implement operations back and forward, which will iterate between states saved in memory (= saved in list memory).

Memory will have only a limited range, for example 20 states, which means when I will have 20 modifications of an image and I do the 21st, I will delete the first state. Probably by operation `memory.RemoveAt(0);`. What will happen with the list then? I need the list with -1 items than the previous list and with shifted indexes.

I have list `list.Count = 20`, I delete the first item, I want `list.Count = 19` and shifted indexes - something like trim free spaces so index 1 of original list will have now index 0 and index 2 of original index will have index 1, etc.. I found a method of list `TrimExcess`, it would do what I want but I'm not sure.

When I will have list of 19 I can save the new state to the last place by `Add()`, so I will have again the list of 20.

Comment: well who is stopping you from trying it out ?

Comment: A stack is probably a better fit here, there are a few similar questions on SO to look at.

Comment: @MikeMiller: A stack is definitely not a better fit. A stack is a LIFO  structure while the OP needs a FIFO structure.

Comment: You should probably reuse old `Bitmap`s somehow. Or at least dispose them.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen A Stack is a good choice if you are keeping snapshots of history and intend to step back through history in reverse order of snapshot. The CSLA.NET framework does this for undo functionality on business objects.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Yes but that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I don't believe the OP has stated what he wants, but is instead asking what happens with indexes on the list.

Comment: @CodeInChaos dispose them? It doesn't happen automatically??
So I should do list[0].Dispose() and then list.RemoveAt(0)??

Comment: Surely this is just a simple memento pattern?

Comment: If we were going with stacks, and both undo and redo functionality, I think you can use two stacks, one for undo and one for redo. When you undo something, you pop it from the undo stack and push it onto the redo stack. When redoing something, you pop it from the redo stack and push it onto the undo stack.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: He sure has stated what he wants: ... "`memory.RemoveAt(0);` ...  I delete first item ... index 1 of original list will have now index 0 ..." That is clearly a FIFO structure.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Fair enough, but this begs the question, is the OP going to fill the structure backwards or have history going in reverse? I dismissed it initially because it sounds ridiculous.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I agree, but that is apparently what the OP wants...

Comment: I imagine he wants to limit the history to a certain number of operations, and by deleting [0] he is deleting the oldest operation. It would be difficult to duplicate this limit with a stack.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ah true, sounds more probable.

Comment: What Thorsten Dittmar wrote was what I needed to know, but thanks for your comments, because I should probably really think about better design opperations undo and rendo.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's exactly what I wanted ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not confuse a `List` with an array. An array has fixed positions and a fixed size, while a list does not.

For arrays, there's not such thing as "adding" or "removing" items. An array always has the length it was assigned when creating it.

A list is dynamic in its length. You add items, the list grows. You remove items, the list shrinks. If you add an item to a list, the item is always appended to the list (you can call `Insert` to insert at a specified position).

However, at any given time, the entries in a list will have indices starting at 0 ranging to `Count-1` ("zero based"). Even if you remove an item at position X "in the middle of the list", there will be an item at that index (the one that was previously at position X+1).

Summary: What you described in the "What I need" paragraph is done automatically without any further actions in your code.

About the `TrimExcess` method: A list has a `Count` (the actual number of elements in the list) and a `Capacity` (the internal number of elements the list can take without having to resize its internal structures). The `Capacity` can be greater than the `Count`. This is, because internally the list stores its items in data structures that need to be reorganized when adding/removing.

To save time when adding, the `Capacity` grows in larger steps. For example, when you add an item to a list that is full, internally 4 new "places" are created, so that consecutive adds don't cause too much overhead.

What `TrimExcess` does is to reorganize the list's internal data structures so that the `Capacity` matches the `Count`. This takes the more time the more items are in the list, so `TrimExcess` should only be called when you're sure that you'll not need to add/remove any elements anymore.

In your case: Hands off the `TrimExcess` method.

**`Capacity` does not limit the list's size! In C#, there's no option to create a list that takes a maximum of X elements. You'll have to do that yourself.**

Comment: Can I have small additional question? Should I have Dispose of Bitmap before removing it? As somebody mentioned? I'm not sure how (if) garbage colector works in this case (removing bitmap from list) in C#. I'm used to work with java and getting know C#

Comment: It's *never* a bad idea to dispose of objects if you know you can. :-) Please note that it might be a good idea to stick to the following order of instructions: `list[x].Dispose(); list.RemoveAt(x);`

Answer (score 7):

The list manages the indices not the objects. So, after `memory.RemoveAt(0)`, the first object in the list (formerly at index 1) will now be at index 0 and count is automatically 19.

Answer (score 2):

Wow I don't believe you guys are complicating this so much.  What the OP wants is exactly what he will get if he tries to do exactly what he described.

```
Memory.RemoveAt(0);
Memory.Add(myBmp);
```

all bitmap indexes will be reduced by 1, the new bitmap will be placed at the end in slot 20.

Comment: True. Then again, he tagged his question "homework", so it can't be that bad to explain how/why things work like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a behavior in List that when you keep adding the elements it will add the items with incremented index. Whereas if you remove one item List.Remove(i) (i would be any index) and then try to add List.Add(j), the item j is added to the top of the stack. That means the j index is 0.